# Accessing the time where a field has been updated (Django models)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to create a system where the user have to change his password every "x" number of days. I managed to achieve this by saving a UTC timestamp representing the time when the user has created/modified his password.

My question is, instead of saving the timestamp in the database, is it possible to get a timestamp representing the time when the field has been changed through some of django's built-in functions? This way I could access when was the last time the user has updated his password without having to add a dedicated field in the model to save the timestamp in it.

Comment: You can do this in DB only. for `datetime` field there is auto add property. Probably you should create `time_updated` field with type datetime.

Comment: You can only store the information about a db model inside that model. Django does not keep a strict check on when the fields were modified(except in Admin but you can't rely on that) in any of its own table. You will have to store it in db there is no disadvantage of this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no field that shows you which field updated in which time, you should implement it your self

you should use `set_password` everywhere to manage update password time

```
password_updated_at = models.DateTimeField(_('password updated at'))

def set_password(self, raw_password):
    r = super(User, self).set_password(raw_password=raw_password)
    self.password_updated_at = timezone.now()
    self.save()
    return r

def is_password_updated_at_expired(self):
    duration = (timezone.now() - self.password_updated_at).total_seconds()
    return duration > settings.PASSWORD_UPDATE_EXPIRE_TIME, duration
```

Comment: I wont be using your suggested code since I already implemented my own code but still you answered with "No" and this seems about correct to me and also agrees with the other comments I received. I will mark your answer as accepted